# C++ Class members specified by template

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use a variadic template to specify the members of a class? An acceptable solution would involve storing the data internally in a tuple.

```
template <typename ... Args> 
struct FromPP {
     // TODO: Get the tuple type from parameter pack
     std::tuple<> data;    
     // TODO: write the constructors

     // Other code... E.g. A print method, and manipulations with 
     // other points of the same type... 
}
```

I would ideally like some implementation that has both default and copy constructors:

```
FromPP<float>();    // decltype(data) == std::tuple<float>
FromPP<float>(1.1); // decltype(data) == std::tuple<float>

FromPP<float,int>();       // decltype(data) == std::tuple<float,int>
FromPP<float,int>(1.1, 5); // decltype(data) == std::tuple<float,int>
```

etc.

If possible, I would like a C++11 solution. Some hardware we use has spotty C++14 support.

Comment: `std::tuple<Args...> data;`

Comment: Just wondering: how is it useful? What do you intend to do what `tuple` can't?

Comment: there's a lot you can do with [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: The class will have some other methods... a print method, and some manipulations with other points of the same type.

Comment: But you can't use this data in these methods, no? Why is it a part of class, no just a separate tuple?

Comment: @dyukha: I do not follow.

Comment: Right now I have a specialized version for 1d, 2d, 3d. I want the general N-d implementation.

Comment: Never mind. I googled and it seems that with some strings attached you can do things such as print, (by the same logic) compare and maybe something else.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. And even if it were possible it woudn't make sense. Templates are a means of reusing code for different types but it seems that you need template specializations to begin with. Also, variadic types use recursion, which can make sense for values but probably not for types. Function overloading can be used in this case.

Comment: I considered that possibility. And you may indeed be right. As I mentioned, I have 1D, 2D, and 3D versions right now, and it just seems to me that perhaps I should make an N-D version. Right now I am using the tuple internally, so it did not seem like a big step. I thought that if somebody had a simple way of accomplishing the above task, then I could mess around with it and see where it leads. Thanks for taking a look though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with the tuple, you can define your struct as follows:

```
template <typename... Args> 
struct FromPP {
   std::tuple<Args...> data;    

   FromPP() = default;
   FromPP(Args&&... args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
};
```

It works with your exemplary code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/163TwS1SrKULgfIH

Is it what you wanted?